# cloud watch alarm for reboot - based on StatusCheckFailed_Instance >=1 for1 datapoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a running EC2 machine in my AWS account, I have created a cloud watch alarm which is based on StatusCheckFailed_Instance >= 1 for 1 data point within 1 minute. If the machine is rebooted within a minute, then I should receive an alert but I am not getting any alert even if the machine reboots.

Is there a way to push the metrics to cloud watch and get the alerts on machine reboot?

Comment: Are you saying CloudWatch is rebooting the instance and failing to notify you? Or are you saying that when you reboot an instance CloudWatch isn't detecting it?

Answer (score 0):

From your post I understand that you basically want to receive a notification when you instance is down or being rebooted (even when it lasts less than a minute).

You can achieve this several ways. Using the cloudwatch agent or a custom script for example, you can push custom metrics in an interval of 10 seconds. Using this, you can for example create a 'heartbeat' metric that is 1 when the instance is available and 0 when something is wrong . Create a high-resolution alarm on that metric with the "treat missing data as breaching" option. This way, when a data point is missing, for example when the instance is rebooting, the alarm will be triggered.

See also [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/07/amazon-cloudwatch-introduces-high-resolution-custom-metrics-and-alarms/) for more info on custom metrics and high resolution alarms.